# Sensor to detect whether string is in tension?

Tags: string

I need a sensor to detect whether there is tension on a string or not. I do not need an accurate measurement of the amount of tension- just whether the string is being pulled on or is taut.

Alternatively, if there is some homemade hack of this sensor, please let me know. I'd love to give it a shot!

Comment: tie the string to a spring loaded lever that closes a switch when the string is pulled

Comment: Tie the string to a *momentary pull switch*. It's like a button but you pull it, not push it.